# DataBinding With Android Dialog

Tags: android, data-binding, android-dialog, android-databinding

I have implemented `DataBinding` in `Activity`, `Fragment` and `RecyclerView`. Now trying to do it in `Dialog`, but little bit confuse about how to set custom view inside it?

Here is code i have implemented for `Dialog`.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.getWindow();

dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

LayoutTermsBinding termsBinding;

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_terms);
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

dialog.show();
```

I know if it is `Activity` we can perform `DataBindingUtil.setContentView()` and for `Fragment` we can perform `DataBindingUtil.inflate()` but i am confuse about how to convert `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_terms);` with `DataBinding`.

Comment: Interesting question.

Comment: Why don't you use DialogFragment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming something like this is your `layout_terms.xml`:

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <!--You don't even need to use this one, this is important/necessary for the inflate method -->
        <variable name="testVariable" value="String" /> 
    </data>
    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

First, you'll need to get your `Binding`. This is done by simply inflating it:

```
/*
* This will only work, if you have a variable or something in your 'layout' tag, 
* maybe build your project beforehand. Only then the inflate method can be found. 
* context - the context you are in. The binding is my activities binding. 
* You can get the root view somehow else.
*/
LayoutTermsBinding termsBinding = LayoutTermsBinding
    .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), (ViewGroup) binding.getRoot(), false);

 //without a variable this would be
LayoutTermsBinding termsBinding = DataBindingUtil.
      inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), R.layout.layout_terms, (ViewGroup) mainBinding.getRoot(), false);
```

Second step: Set your `termsBinding.getRoot()` as `ContentView`:

```
dialog.setContentView(termsBinding.getRoot());
```

And you're done. :)

Comment: There is a slight change, you might forget it, i have added my answer.

Comment: However your answer is absolutely correct if i have included my view, but here i am using dialog so that will be in another xml file and cannot include that in my main xml.

Comment: I have written as a comment in my code, that you'll need to use a variable in your `<data>` tag to use it this way. If you would have posted more information, I could have also provided you your solution. ;)

Comment: yes right, but i have mentioned in my question that i want binding in my dialog to set custom view, so obviously that view cannot be included in xml or i cannot use it in `<data>`

Comment: anyways, your answer gave me some hint and i have found solution for that, thanks :)

Comment: I meant the `<data>` tag in your `R.layout.layout_terms` - if there is a `variable`, the `inflate` method in `LayoutTermsBinding` will be "provided".

Comment: yes but my question was about how to set custom view in dialog with use of binding, if i will bind that view to dialog then only `<data>` tag inside `R.layout.layout_terms` will be usefull right?

Comment: I have added something to my answer for more clarity. Basically, both methods are the same, I like the one with the variable more, because it is less to write (no need to remember the layout id).